# Переклад для "defence in depth"

Tags: переклад, from-english

В інформаційній безпеці є термін "[defence in depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defense_in_depth_(computing))" — коли захист організовано у кілька шарів (layers) і кожний шар протистоїть загрозі певного виду.

Також хотілося б знайти кращий аналог для "layer" у такому контексті. Схоже, що "коло безпеки" або "шар безпеки" ніде не використовуються.

Comment: Питанꙇа красше розмежувати окремими запитами.

Comment: дякую, але в даному випадку це сильно пов'язані питання. Оборона складається з цих самих layers, тому це скоріш за все мають бути однокореневі слова

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Прямим перекладом буде **оборона в глибинї**, що і зробили Польською — [obrona w głąb](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Obrona_w_g%C5%82%C4%85b_(informatyka)). Японцї натомість [переклали](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%A4%9A%E5%B1%A4%E9%98%B2%E5%BE%A1_(%E3%82%BB%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A5%E3%83%AA%E3%83%86%E3%82%A3)) як **багатошарова оборона**.

Таку тямку уже знають щонайменше [два](https://e2u.org.ua/s?w=defence+in+depth&dicts=all&highlight=on) словника:

1. [Новий українсько-англійський словник](https://e2u.org.ua/dicts/common18) 2016 (Є. І. Гороть, С. В. Гончарук, Л. К. Малімон, О. О. Рогач.)
2. [Українсько-англійський словник ділової людини](https://e2u.org.ua/dicts/dilovyi) 2014 (Є. І. Гороть, О. В. Василенко, Н. В. Єфремова [та ін.])

Обидва перекладають як **ешелонована оборона**:

> **ешелонован||ий** : **~а оборона** defence in depth.